# ORA-10722: invalid number - triggered by GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this that runs fine:

```
SELECT t1.fiscal_quarter, t2.destination_country
FROM 
    (SELECT fiscal_quarter, order_number FROM tbl1) t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT order_number, destination_country FROM tbl2) t2
ON t1.order_number = t2.order_number
;
```

But when I try to add any sort of `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT t1.fiscal_quarter, t2.destination_country
FROM 
    (SELECT fiscal_quarter, order_number FROM tbl1) t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT order_number, destination_country FROM tbl2) t2
ON t1.order_number = t2.order_number
GROUP BY t1.fiscal_quarter, t2.destination_country
;
```

I see the error message `ORA-01722: invalid number`. The datatypes are as follows:

- `t1.fiscal_quarter: VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)`
- `t1.order_number: VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)`
- `t2.order_number: NUMBER`
- `t2.destination_country: VARCHAR2(60 BYTE)`

I am guessing this has something to do with the query optimizer converting `t1.order_number` to datatype `NUMBER` in the `LEFT JOIN` but I don't know why this only becomes a problem when I use the `GROUP BY`. Can this be accomplished without changing datatypes for the `order_number` fields?

Comment: If you suspect what you suspect, which is a good guess by the way, you can test your hypothesis. This will help in solving your problem - either you identify the root cause, or you know to look for it elsewhere. Here is how you can test it: what happens if you try to `select order_number + 3 from glo_wrk_ro`? If there are strings that are invalid as numbers, that smaller SELECT can tell you that. Try to isolate the issue, then we can talk about fixes.

Comment: I suppose the first query runs fine up to a point. Most tools select then first n rows. You may get the error in a later row. Scroll down or whatever is necessary to tell the tool to select the remaining rows.

Comment: I'd try `ON t1.order_number = CAST(t2.order_number AS VARCHAR2(255))`.

Comment: @jarlh - that will hide the problem. The best action, at this point, is to identify the data problem, and to discuss it with the business users. Then, if they are OK with it, the OP can use the workaround you suggested. But that shouldn't be the first action - certainly not without letting the business users that there is a problem in the data.

Comment: @mathguy, it's not my fault OP doesn't want to alter column data types. (Which was going to be my next recommendation.)

Comment: Use this to find the faulty order numbers: `select * from glo_wrk_ro.payment_file_ver2 where to_number(order_number default '-99999' on conversion error) = -99999;`.

Comment: "Can this be accomplished without changing datatypes?" -- Yes, force conversion to `VARCHAR` instead of `NUMBER`, and problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Why this only becomes a problem when I use `GROUP BY`"

As Thorsten Kettner suggested in a Comment to your question, it is very likely that the same issue exists in the first query (the join without the aggregation at the end). You are probably viewing "output" in a GUI, a client program like Toad or SQL Developer. These programs retrieve, say, the first 200 rows from the join - as produced by the query execution engine - and display them to you, and they **pause** (they let the engine work on other things) until you press something in your GUI to select the next batch of rows (for example, the next 200 rows). And, as Thorsten explained, if you keep asking for more and more rows, at some point the execution will come to a string value that can't be converted to number and it will throw an error.

Why doesn't this work the same with GROUP BY? Why does that throw an error without showing you any output? That is because it is impossible to generate even a single aggregate row if ALL the rows from the join haven't been generated yet. Think about it - how can you show ANY group, at any point during the join, if you haven't seen the LAST row generated by the join? How do you know that the last row from the join doesn't affect the group you want to show in the output window?

So - this tells you why GROUP BY seems to behave differently from the join query. It doesn't - it's just an optical illusion.

How to fix: Best to find out the faulty values, and understand what they were supposed to mean. If some clown entered `'ten'` when they meant `'10'`, perhaps you can take an educated guess. If you see `'N/A'`, perhaps they meant `null`. In any case, find the data issues and FIX THEM (with your business user's collaboration, most likely) before you use any workaround. If you go straight to the workaround, you will likely get results that are different from those desired and expected. You have a few suggestions as to how to approach finding the faulty data in the Comments below your question.

Answer (score 2):

You would see the problem with the `left join` if you returned *all* the rows.  In addition, any operation that caused the entire result set to be generated would also trigger the problem.  This would include:

```
count(*) over ()
order by <most things>
```

You can find the offending values using regular expressions:

```
select t1.*
from tbl1 t1
where not regexp_like(order_number, '^[0-9]+$');
```

This makes the reasonable assumption that an order number only consists of digits.

What can you do?  An easy solution is to convert the number to a string, which is mentioned in a comment:

```
ON t1.order_number = CAST(t2.order_number AS VARCHAR2(255))
```

This is dangerouss -- the reason that I'm answering -- because it does not handle leading zeros.  So, '009999' is not the same as '9999', alas.

In Oracle, you can use `to_char()` -- if the order length is fixed:

```
ON t1.order_number = to_char(t2.order_number, '000000000') -- or however long the order number is
```

Or, you can convert to a number, ignoring errors in the more recent versions of Oracle:

```
ON to_number(t1.order_number default null on conversion error) = t2.order_number
```

Or a `case` expression should be safe:

```
ON (case when regexp_like(t1.order_number, '^[0-9]+$')
         then to_number(t1.order_number)
    end) = t2.order_number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force conversion to `VARCHAR` to produce the result.

It's not clear those results will be accurate, but at least you'll be able to get the data, or at least parts of it. For example:

```
SELECT t1.fiscal_quarter, t2.destination_country
FROM 
  (SELECT fiscal_quarter, order_number FROM tbl1) t1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     '' || order_number as order_number, -- changed here
     destination_country
   FROM tbl2) t2
ON t1.order_number = t2.order_number;
```

Result:

```
 FISCAL_QUARTER  DESTINATION_COUNTRY 
 --------------- ------------------- 
 2020-01         France              
 2020-01         UK                  
 2020-02
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a3d6560853e98a04f6857e76f9f3e93e).